# iFrames and detecting focus again

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling for some time with this - I have a document that is essentially this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        some divs and stuff

        <div id="content">
            <iframe src="" id="content_frame"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is essential with this particular page is that it knows when anything on the page has focus. This is actually pretty easy, and works with two simple functions:

```
window.onblur=function(){   // when you leave the window
    if(conn != null) {
        if (document.activeElement == document.getElementById("content_frame")) {               
                    send_message_to_server(JSON.stringify({'type':'upd','ele':'vis','status':true}));
        beep_off(conn.peer);
        } else {
            send_message_to_server(JSON.stringify({'type':'upd','ele':'vis','status':false}));
            beep_on(conn.peer);
        }
    }
};

window.onfocus=function(){  // when you focus the window
    if(conn != null) {
        send_message_to_server(JSON.stringify({'type':'upd','ele':'vis','status':true}));
        beep_off(conn.peer);
    }
};
```

The problem I am having is that when the "iframe" is selected, it has focus - this means when the window blurs (change tab or whatever), the iframe still has focus within the window and so fires a message like it still has focus.

In short what I need is:

- If the iframe or the regular part of the site has focus, it fires "true".
- If none of the site has focus (they might have clicked developer tools, the search bar, changed tabs etc) it fires "false".

Currently what I have is:

- When the site has focus it fires "true". (good)
- However if the iframe has focus and then you change tabs, clicked developer tools or address bar etc, it still fires "true". (bad)
- If anything else has focus and you change tabs, clicked developer tools or address bar etc, it fires "false". (good)

What I have also tried:

- Many permutations of the above code.
- $('iframe').is(':focus'); as a flag for if the iframe has focus or not (this doesn't seem to work).

Comment: What is `conn`? Where is it defined?

Comment: `activeElement` is for form elements. `window.onfocus` could be stuck on iframe because an iframe has it's own window object as well as it's own document.

Comment: conn is a p2p connection to a host - basically its trying to update the host on when the user leaves the window.

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` is a completely different context. You'll need to set up event handlers on the iframe's document, and proxy those events back to the main window by using something like `iframe.postMessage` or `window.top`. If you use `postMessage` you'll need to listen for `message` events in the parent window and parse those accordingly to figure out what events were fired inside the `iframe`.

Comment: thanks - do you mean on the document itself? The document itself is likely to be a google form or something like that...

Comment: I'm afraid that's not doable if you're hosting a different domain inside the iframe as far as I know. Even trying to access the `iframe.contentWindow` will throw. This is a browser security limitation that prevents you from tampering with pages from another domain.
`iframes` are very limited in that regard, you should consider an alternative, maybe opening a new window that can communicate with its parent.

Comment: Ah ok, thats a shame - the new window wont work because my javascript needs to have control over the window, including the iframe (although not what is inside the iframe, my JS has no control over that). Ill give something like embed a go to see if it works any differently...

Comment: If you explain what you need this for I might be able to help better. You can do more stuff with a new window, you don't need an iframe in that case.

Comment: Im creating a website which helps examine students. The teacher creates a host and then students connect. The teacher can then pause, send messages, direct the students to the test etc. However so students dont cheat (or so its harder to) I want the teacher to know when they navigate away from that page.

Comment: And why do you need the iframe? You can do all of that with just a regular HTML page.

Comment: Hm, how? Surely there needs to be some javascript of mine running on the page? I used an iframe as I thought they would need my code running to control the page... how would you suggest doing this with just an HTML page?

Comment: I still don't know why you need the iframe. Your description is about a website, so HTML pages that serve some content. Each page can just detect if the focus went away from it, what role does the iframe play here?

Comment: Ok, so imagine the student just navigated to a google form to fill in their test. That website is google forms. It doesn't send the teacher any information about what the student is doing on that tab. The page I have made has my own javascript which connects to the server, sends updates on what the user is doing etc. The iframe is needed as the user is taking a test on another website, such as google forms. There is a test part of the page, and a monitoring part of the page. If it just went to google forms, surely I couldn't monitor that (or add divs to pause their screen, send messages etc)

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I don't know of a way for you to wrap another website inside an iframe and still have full control this way, the browser just wouldn't let you. You could write the code for the test yourself though, it shouldn't be that complicated adding checkboxes and text areas, and it'll give you full control.

Comment: Hi Yasser, thanks for the continued help. I had considered that, but google forms has some really good scripts which auto grade and do some cool stuff. A MCQ section should be easy though so maybe I will look into that :) I do have a good amount of control its just not total - but as you say maybe iust asking too much.